# Interactive liquid or underwater effect on svg or canvas

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRIPK.png)

I need an effect like the one for the letters at the beggining of this page when you move the mouse around https://www.vincentsaisset.com/ this won't be applied to the whole graphic only the pink figure from the bottom, I tried with this [pen](https://codepen.io/alexmoralex/pen/WNQQBBG) but it didn't work.

I tried with vanilla JS and an svg

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('#main')
let shape = document.querySelector('#shape')
let width = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let height = svg.getBoundingClientRect().height;

let wrapper = svg

const conv = {
  '1': '-15', 
  '2': '-12', 
  '3': '-9', 
  '4': '-6', 
  '5': '-3', 
  '6': '0',
  '7': '3',
  '8': '6',
  '9': '9',
  '10': '12',
  '11': '15'
}

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  x = Math.round((e.clientX / width)*10);
  y = Math.round((e.clientY / height)*10);
  console.log(x,y)
  shape.style.transform = `skew(${conv[x]}deg,${conv[y]}deg)`
})

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
shape.classList.remove('transition')
})

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  shape.classList.add('transition');
  shape.style.transform = `skew(0deg,0deg)`
})
```

```css
#main{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.transition{
  transition: .5s transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
```

```html
<p>Effect applies inside the square</p> 
<svg id="main" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="282px" height="282px" viewBox="0 0 282 282" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <path d="M0 0L171.656 0L171.656 179.803L0 179.803L0 0Z" transform="translate(0 0.8178374)" id="path_1"/>
    <clipPath id="mask_1">
      <use xlink:href="#path_1"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g >
    <g transform="translate(57 0)"> 
      <g transform="translate(0 63.233)">
        <g id="shape">
        <path d="M0 0L171.656 0L171.656 179.803L0 179.803L0 0Z" transform="translate(0 0.8178374)" id="Clip-2" fill="none" stroke="none"/>
        <g clip-path="url(#mask_1)">
          <path d="M36.6762 3.54856C40.5902 -1.40844 50.6802 -0.505437 56.3822 2.21156C62.0832 4.92756 66.2392 10.0066 70.2022 14.9246C79.0482 25.9026 88.4592 37.2866 101.472 42.7096C115.653 48.6196 132.204 46.5936 146.313 52.6726C158.464 57.9076 167.794 69.2556 170.582 82.1896C171.8 87.8366 171.831 93.6776 171.413 99.4386C170.672 109.649 168.529 119.757 165.061 129.389C163.537 133.623 161.733 137.81 159.044 141.419C155.052 146.774 149.337 150.565 143.545 153.893C139.125 156.433 134.541 158.789 129.612 160.088C110.453 165.136 88.9632 153.709 70.8192 161.665C62.8702 165.151 56.8142 171.938 49.1382 175.992C36.7502 182.535 20.1032 180.603 10.3002 170.592C2.08124 162.201 -0.618762 149.66 0.115238 137.937C0.850238 126.215 4.59324 114.926 7.62924 103.58C12.4872 85.4236 15.5882 66.7976 16.8752 48.0476C17.3272 41.4586 17.5652 34.7976 19.2592 28.4146C21.9492 18.2816 28.3882 9.19056 37.0542 3.29156L36.6762 3.54856Z" transform="translate(-0.0001378642 0.8178374)" id="Fill-1" fill="#EDD0D3" stroke="none"/>
        </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      
      <path d="M0 5.946C0 9.23 2.662 11.892 5.946 11.892C9.23 11.892 11.893 9.23 11.893 5.946C11.893 2.662 9.23 0 5.946 0C2.662 0 0 2.662 0 5.946" transform="translate(89.6487 67.5997)" id="Fill-6" fill="#EDD0D3" stroke="none"/>
      <g id="Group-14" transform="translate(19 39.233)">
        <path d="M2.97635 152.145C1.84135 150.546 0.887349 148.836 0.110349 147.036C-0.496651 145.634 1.57035 144.409 2.18235 145.825C7.97035 159.212 23.4703 165.903 37.0434 168.108C48.6183 169.989 60.7313 168.704 71.7624 164.678C71.8943 164.074 72.0263 163.477 72.1573 162.904C74.0443 154.642 77.4333 146.689 82.0823 139.605C84.4223 136.039 87.0704 132.597 90.0643 129.555C92.6924 126.884 96.3354 124.503 100.211 125.88C103.441 127.028 105.724 130.238 106.309 133.549C107.025 137.611 105.322 141.625 103.025 144.897C98.7063 151.05 92.6373 156.181 86.3253 160.191C82.4004 162.684 78.2194 164.777 73.8733 166.453C73.6753 167.535 73.4983 168.621 73.3553 169.712C72.8803 173.353 72.4263 177.568 74.1713 180.956C76.0753 184.655 80.4583 186.21 83.9743 187.945C88.2493 190.052 92.5243 192.159 96.7993 194.267C98.4933 195.103 100.186 195.938 101.881 196.773C110.694 180.833 118.276 164.225 124.487 147.101C127.628 138.443 130.572 129.64 132.867 120.715C133.925 116.602 134.778 112.224 134.113 107.973C133.497 104.041 131.438 100.579 128.186 98.2673C119.851 92.3423 109.2 94.9853 100.745 99.1693C100.4 99.3393 100.066 99.3383 99.7803 99.2303C99.2713 100.369 98.7343 101.496 98.1473 102.598C96.0203 106.598 93.2723 110.302 90.4483 113.834C84.7973 120.9 77.2253 127.152 67.7753 127.5C63.4683 127.658 59.2903 126.343 55.8873 123.696C52.7363 121.244 50.3904 117.901 48.5563 114.388C47.9943 113.312 47.4734 112.211 46.9773 111.098C45.2793 111.832 43.4613 112.328 41.5363 112.499C32.4563 113.306 25.1893 106.398 21.0353 99.0573C16.2483 90.5963 14.2513 80.8053 15.9363 71.1883C16.3743 68.6863 17.0583 66.2413 17.8933 63.8443C18.3993 62.3953 20.7183 63.0183 20.2083 64.4823C17.1943 73.1303 16.8783 82.2073 19.9373 90.8963C22.5733 98.3793 27.4303 106.537 35.3233 109.291C38.9823 110.568 42.7174 110.256 46.0333 108.843C45.0644 106.444 44.2023 103.997 43.4203 101.549C41.8733 96.7073 40.7253 91.6943 40.4543 86.6053C40.2293 82.4043 40.2103 76.9863 42.8153 73.4133C45.2313 70.0993 49.6653 69.7623 53.0623 71.7613C56.8763 74.0043 58.4663 78.5363 59.2463 82.6543C60.1083 87.2053 60.1553 91.9553 58.9993 96.4613C57.5693 102.033 54.0073 107.1 49.1323 110.008C49.3533 110.507 49.5643 111.012 49.7983 111.505C53.0074 118.272 58.1133 124.725 66.1953 125.095C74.8223 125.49 82.0663 120.03 87.3963 113.78C92.8433 107.393 97.2523 100.345 99.8673 92.3433C102.449 84.4433 103.678 76.1783 104.824 67.9703C105.06 66.2783 105.295 64.5843 105.533 62.8913C104.3 62.3483 103.05 61.8473 101.789 61.3803C101.539 61.3583 101.293 61.2723 101.091 61.1173C97.4223 59.7893 93.6794 58.6593 90.0253 57.2863C90.0036 57.2839 89.9823 57.2842 89.9611 57.2845C89.9286 57.2849 89.8962 57.2854 89.8624 57.2763C89.7193 57.2373 89.5854 57.1653 89.4663 57.0733C88.2743 56.6163 87.0903 56.1393 85.9263 55.6063C84.5233 54.9653 85.7413 52.8953 87.1373 53.5343C87.7643 53.8213 88.4013 54.0853 89.0383 54.3483C89.0023 54.2183 88.9714 54.0863 88.9253 53.9593C88.9073 53.9103 88.8833 53.8543 88.8683 53.8223C88.8303 53.7403 88.7923 53.6583 88.7504 53.5783C88.6503 53.3873 88.5263 53.2123 88.4213 53.0253C88.3823 52.957 88.4392 53.1219 88.4383 53.1222C88.4378 53.1224 88.4077 53.0387 88.2924 52.7263C88.2813 52.6993 88.2754 52.6863 88.2683 52.6703C88.2263 52.5983 88.1843 52.5253 88.1433 52.4533C88.1323 52.4343 88.1374 52.4393 88.1323 52.4293C88.1264 52.4223 88.1293 52.4273 88.1213 52.4173C87.3913 51.5893 86.3663 50.9123 85.5603 50.0893C85.1933 50.6623 84.8293 51.2383 84.4824 51.8243C83.6094 53.3033 82.7403 54.2573 80.8803 53.9803C78.9673 53.6953 77.1684 52.5053 75.6033 51.4393C73.6954 50.1373 71.8863 48.6903 70.1173 47.2033C70.3493 48.7313 70.5773 50.2613 70.7993 51.7913C71.8163 58.8033 73.0803 65.7743 74.1993 72.7693C74.3513 73.7233 74.4933 74.6803 74.6393 75.6373C74.8193 75.2683 75.0063 74.9043 75.1823 74.5343C78.0014 68.6603 80.6983 62.6673 82.6833 56.4533C83.1513 54.9883 85.4703 55.6143 84.9984 57.0913C82.4963 64.9233 79.0163 72.5143 75.2513 79.8623C75.4193 81.0823 75.5923 82.3023 75.7324 83.5263C76.0544 86.3193 76.2174 89.3143 75.3233 92.0263C74.5854 94.2623 72.7533 97.1393 70.1223 97.2893C67.2903 97.4513 65.8624 94.4163 66.3413 91.9753C66.6793 90.2503 67.7373 88.7413 68.5913 87.2373C69.3133 85.9643 70.0163 84.6803 70.7063 83.3883C71.4164 82.0573 72.1084 80.7173 72.7914 79.3713C72.7443 79.0533 72.6973 78.7333 72.6513 78.4153C71.7293 72.0533 70.5853 65.7263 69.5524 59.3813C68.7633 54.5343 68.1223 49.6643 67.3443 44.8153C65.5703 43.2683 63.8123 41.7003 62.0963 40.0923C60.0923 38.2133 58.2213 35.5063 59.2503 32.6503C60.0923 30.3133 62.6723 28.8433 65.0033 30.1133C66.9313 31.1633 67.6373 33.4883 68.0554 35.4953C68.6143 38.1713 69.0984 40.8573 69.5414 43.5513C71.1053 44.9193 72.6853 46.2703 74.3263 47.5443C76.1033 48.9263 78.0193 50.4253 80.1233 51.2823C80.5583 51.4593 81.2753 51.6893 81.6273 51.6503C81.8351 51.6279 81.8383 51.6196 81.8484 51.5938C81.8523 51.5839 81.8572 51.5713 81.8753 51.5543C82.1124 51.3323 82.3793 50.6633 82.5873 50.3183C84.1493 47.7323 85.9464 45.2953 87.4283 42.6603C87.9653 41.7083 89.1553 42.0363 89.5393 42.7863C90.2673 43.2803 90.9953 43.7723 91.7224 44.2653C95.7663 38.1923 99.1323 31.1403 100.598 24.0123C100.91 22.5003 101.115 20.9433 101.007 19.3963C100.888 17.7063 100.208 16.0003 99.4703 14.4953C97.6703 10.8253 94.8214 7.7053 91.3593 5.5373C87.5383 3.1453 82.9563 1.8953 78.4473 2.5023C76.9373 2.7053 76.2833 0.393298 77.8093 0.188298C86.6163 -0.996701 95.3013 3.5133 100.144 10.8453C102.27 14.0633 103.723 17.8223 103.358 21.7183C103.047 25.0403 102.081 28.2833 100.888 31.4063C101.293 31.3663 101.713 31.5173 101.988 31.9613C104.46 35.9443 105.692 40.6653 105.414 45.3523C105.272 47.7313 104.677 49.9533 103.976 52.2183C103.256 54.5493 102.943 56.8953 103.009 59.3103C104.505 59.8653 105.988 60.4523 107.443 61.1183C107.967 61.3583 108.065 61.9803 107.995 62.4733C106.689 71.6423 105.641 80.9053 103.132 89.8453C102.509 92.0643 101.791 94.2623 100.958 96.4153C108.645 92.8473 117.464 90.7163 125.587 94.1163C129.176 95.6183 132.391 98.1143 134.368 101.506C136.578 105.299 137.017 109.799 136.556 114.094C136.063 118.699 134.731 123.155 133.426 127.58C132.032 132.3 130.539 136.991 128.947 141.647C125.779 150.913 122.217 160.043 118.289 169.013C113.815 179.227 108.847 189.221 103.421 198.961C103.09 199.556 102.351 199.674 101.779 199.392C99.5294 198.283 97.2803 197.174 95.0313 196.065C94.0173 199.999 93.0043 203.933 91.9903 207.866C91.3763 210.25 90.7003 212.624 90.2494 215.045C89.1953 220.691 89.1553 226.496 90.0153 232.169C90.3703 234.507 90.7273 236.935 89.5603 239.114C88.6043 240.898 86.7163 242.081 84.6613 241.729C80.3053 240.98 78.2063 235.089 76.7263 231.573C74.8513 227.116 73.3743 222.463 70.9304 218.268C68.6374 214.329 64.3853 211.302 63.9173 206.505C63.4363 201.575 66.5903 197.995 70.6483 195.773C73.8543 194.016 78.5104 192.677 79.9733 188.952C80.0104 188.862 80.0533 188.779 80.1013 188.704C78.4613 187.897 76.8273 187.066 75.3693 185.951C69.7313 181.646 70.0093 174.07 71.2123 167.42C62.2823 170.471 52.7483 171.79 43.3513 171.206C35.9133 170.743 28.5663 169.094 21.6973 166.194C14.4563 163.135 7.58135 158.628 2.97635 152.145ZM66.6903 41.0773C65.0473 39.6983 63.2643 38.2593 62.1353 36.5333C61.3843 35.3863 60.9633 33.8583 61.9273 32.6923C62.5043 31.9933 63.3653 31.8293 64.1063 32.3713C65.4423 33.3473 65.6733 35.7113 65.9464 37.1993C66.1843 38.4943 66.4413 39.7853 66.6903 41.0773ZM91.5443 55.3313C94.5273 56.4383 97.5643 57.3993 100.573 58.4383C100.583 56.6293 100.8 54.8243 101.239 53.0643C101.816 50.7513 102.711 48.5683 102.949 46.1743C103.392 41.7243 102.368 37.2793 100.075 33.4543C100.049 33.5163 100.024 33.5793 99.9993 33.6423C98.1363 38.1013 95.9083 42.4503 93.1623 46.4353C92.9453 46.7493 92.6543 46.9113 92.3513 46.9573C92.0203 47.0953 91.6403 47.1023 91.3223 46.8873C90.4623 46.3043 89.6013 45.7213 88.7413 45.1393C88.1543 46.1013 87.5483 47.0523 86.9273 47.9933C86.9313 48.0003 86.9343 48.0053 86.9373 48.0093C86.9563 48.0313 86.9723 48.0533 86.9913 48.0743C87.0533 48.1453 87.1173 48.2153 87.1823 48.2833C87.5153 48.6323 87.8853 48.9463 88.2523 49.2583C88.9783 49.8763 89.7503 50.4923 90.2613 51.3123C90.3623 51.4743 90.4253 51.6573 90.5003 51.8313C90.5213 51.8593 90.5463 51.8933 90.5623 51.9173C90.7403 52.1803 90.8823 52.4703 91.0103 52.7613C91.3663 53.5733 91.5883 54.4543 91.5443 55.3313ZM48.1684 107.742C47.0883 105.062 46.1453 102.317 45.3163 99.5643C43.9563 95.0523 42.9633 90.4023 42.8144 85.6793C42.7024 82.1393 42.5533 76.7663 45.3803 74.0953C48.4864 71.1603 52.9963 73.8843 54.7753 76.8973C56.8293 80.3763 57.4393 84.8793 57.4833 88.8543C57.5303 93.0933 56.6893 97.4013 54.5863 101.115C53.0313 103.861 50.7863 106.155 48.1684 107.742ZM73.5763 86.9683C73.5623 85.8213 73.4663 84.6743 73.3423 83.5303C73.1814 83.8333 73.0233 84.1393 72.8624 84.4423C71.7794 86.4753 70.6093 88.4573 69.5023 90.4763C68.9143 91.5493 68.2193 92.9673 68.8903 94.1643C69.6713 95.5563 71.0143 94.5383 71.7623 93.6613C73.3223 91.8373 73.6033 89.2753 73.5763 86.9683ZM75.9864 157.975C75.3963 159.838 74.8833 161.729 74.4493 163.637C75.4864 163.208 76.5163 162.765 77.5303 162.287C83.8033 159.333 89.6374 155.45 94.6794 150.685C99.3253 146.293 106.649 138.9 103.27 131.884C101.703 128.63 98.3344 126.823 94.9604 128.686C93.2784 129.614 91.9314 131.027 90.6503 132.433C89.2853 133.932 87.9823 135.489 86.7624 137.108C82.0284 143.392 78.3633 150.475 75.9864 157.975ZM82.2143 189.745C84.1664 190.708 86.1183 191.67 88.0704 192.633C89.6573 193.415 91.2454 194.199 92.8324 194.981C91.7263 199.27 90.6224 203.559 89.5163 207.849C88.8963 210.255 88.2334 212.65 87.8103 215.102C86.9384 220.154 86.7644 225.317 87.3694 230.409C87.4339 230.953 87.538 231.531 87.6451 232.125C87.9862 234.017 88.3572 236.075 87.5733 237.742C86.4333 240.167 84.1814 239.439 82.7453 237.773C81.3273 236.129 80.3904 233.97 79.5114 232.006C78.5473 229.857 77.7214 227.649 76.8594 225.458C75.2484 221.366 73.5154 217.286 70.7934 213.791C69.4564 212.075 67.7344 210.525 66.8584 208.496C65.9503 206.398 66.1003 203.886 67.2064 201.892C68.8894 198.856 72.5203 197.514 75.4513 196.025C78.3184 194.567 80.9464 192.801 82.2143 189.745Z" transform="translate(0.4776511 0.2090015)" id="Fill-12" fill="#143258" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
      </g>
      <path d="M26.6556 18.0769C30.2276 18.6879 33.9086 18.6669 37.4816 17.9669C38.9896 17.6719 39.6357 19.9849 38.1186 20.2819C34.2306 21.0429 30.2276 21.0839 26.3416 20.4379C25.8717 23.0079 25.0336 25.5129 23.8806 27.8519C21.9956 31.6749 19.1456 34.8809 16.1206 37.8399C15.4787 38.4679 14.8037 39.1113 14.1116 39.7709C8.0029 45.5933 0.560824 52.6865 2.73365 61.7209C3.09365 63.2219 0.78065 63.8619 0.41965 62.3589C-1.33235 55.0739 2.66665 48.0759 7.49665 42.9089C12.6296 37.4179 18.9986 32.9049 22.1736 25.8689C22.9706 24.1019 23.6086 22.0749 24.0026 19.9629C20.6546 19.1549 17.4296 17.8259 14.4876 15.9769C11.3946 14.0329 7.97265 11.3819 7.34665 7.54293C6.69165 3.51693 9.42965 0.46193 13.3716 0.0499295C17.0546 -0.33507 20.7566 1.54593 23.0926 4.32893C25.7497 7.49393 26.7896 11.6679 26.7796 15.7369C26.7776 16.5189 26.7286 17.2989 26.6556 18.0769ZM13.8476 12.6409C16.9837 14.9709 20.5737 16.6289 24.3417 17.5779C24.7776 12.6869 23.7106 7.67893 19.9306 4.55893C17.5756 2.61593 12.8316 1.06093 10.4627 3.86093C7.83365 6.96793 11.4286 10.8429 13.8476 12.6409Z" transform="translate(55.99165 22.37397)" id="Fill-15" fill="#143258" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
      <path d="M2.21222 0.578173C2.36522 0.917173 2.53922 1.24617 2.73622 1.56217C2.83022 1.71217 2.92922 1.85917 3.03222 2.00317C3.05822 2.03917 3.09222 2.08417 3.10822 2.10617C3.16122 2.17317 3.21522 2.23917 3.27022 2.30417C3.49922 2.57417 3.74622 2.82917 4.00722 3.06917C4.13722 3.18917 4.27322 3.30417 4.40822 3.41717C4.43222 3.43717 4.44322 3.44717 4.45722 3.45817C4.47122 3.46817 4.48122 3.47517 4.50222 3.49117C4.57422 3.54317 4.64622 3.59517 4.71922 3.64517C5.01022 3.84817 5.31422 4.03217 5.62722 4.19817C5.80022 4.28917 5.97622 4.37317 6.15322 4.45417C6.17922 4.46617 6.17922 4.46617 6.19122 4.47217C6.19622 4.47417 6.19222 4.47117 6.20922 4.47717C6.29322 4.50617 6.37522 4.54117 6.45822 4.57117C6.79122 4.69117 7.13122 4.79117 7.47722 4.86817C7.66722 4.91017 7.85822 4.94217 8.04922 4.97417C8.06622 4.97517 8.07722 4.97617 8.10222 4.97817C8.20722 4.98717 8.31422 4.99617 8.42022 5.00417C9.04522 5.04617 9.64922 5.52618 9.61922 6.20418C9.59222 6.81817 9.09022 7.44918 8.42022 7.40418C4.91822 7.16818 1.60422 5.01517 0.14022 1.78917C-0.11878 1.21917 -0.0427804 0.472173 0.56922 0.147173C1.09622 -0.129827 1.93522 -0.0318271 2.21222 0.578173" transform="translate(103.334 63.20483)" id="Fill-17" fill="#143258" stroke="none"/>
      <g id="Group" transform="matrix(-1 8.742278E-08 -8.742278E-08 -1 148.4601 48.00022)">
        <path d="M15.4304 0.325571C18.1484 3.02657 21.3614 5.16257 24.9314 6.56557C26.3534 7.12357 25.7344 9.44557 24.2934 8.87957C21.2974 7.70257 18.5274 6.10457 16.0464 4.09657C16.4184 7.81557 16.9454 11.5156 17.6534 15.1866C17.6894 15.3656 17.7314 15.5446 17.7664 15.7236C19.0764 16.2216 20.4264 16.7036 21.5444 17.4946C22.8424 18.4106 23.7224 19.8096 23.6004 21.4416C23.4854 22.9826 22.3304 24.2466 20.7604 24.3446C17.1114 24.5706 16.1884 20.4476 15.6324 17.4026C15.2394 17.2486 14.8494 17.0936 14.4764 16.9216C12.3644 15.9446 10.3044 14.8626 8.25041 13.7716C5.11141 12.1046 1.67141 10.3196 0.120411 6.92757C-0.516589 5.53257 1.55041 4.31257 2.19341 5.71657C3.71441 9.04357 7.36841 10.5966 10.4254 12.2106C11.9734 13.0266 13.5354 13.8156 15.1174 14.5646C14.3094 10.1346 13.7274 5.66457 13.3814 1.17457C13.2994 0.106571 14.7334 -0.367429 15.4304 0.325571ZM20.0304 19.3646C19.5074 19.0216 18.9314 18.7426 18.3404 18.4836C18.3594 18.5646 18.3724 18.6466 18.3914 18.7266C18.6074 19.6726 18.8044 20.9126 19.6004 21.5686C20.0924 21.9746 20.9904 22.2136 21.1954 21.3996C21.4164 20.5276 20.6804 19.7906 20.0304 19.3646Z" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0.5777186 47.85629)" id="Fill-19" fill="#143258" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"/>
        <path d="M15.7326 5.61038C14.7996 4.94238 13.8666 4.27338 12.9336 3.60538C13.0846 6.58938 13.5006 9.54738 14.2086 12.4604C14.4736 13.5554 13.3796 14.2284 12.4456 13.8164C7.93063 11.8264 3.82463 8.98138 0.35063 5.47838C-0.73837 4.38038 0.95863 2.68238 2.04763 3.78138C4.79063 6.54738 7.93363 8.84038 11.3716 10.6344C10.7796 7.53338 10.4646 4.38238 10.4616 1.22338C10.4606 0.377379 11.5056 -0.357621 12.2666 0.187379C13.8256 1.30438 15.3846 2.42138 16.9436 3.53838C17.4696 3.91538 17.7226 4.58338 17.3746 5.17938C17.0706 5.69938 16.2616 5.98938 15.7326 5.61038" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 13.9387)" id="Fill-21" fill="#143258" stroke="none"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: As far as an SVG solution goes, the approach I would take is to convert your blob to a polygon, with lots of vertices.  Then when the mouse moves over the SVG, move every point in the polygon away from the mouse position. The amount of movement should be proportional to how close the polygon point is to the pointer.